# Best way to organize third party libraries with console applications

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I build a large number of console applications to run business processes around here. Most are all of the same nature, they get deployed to the application servers, access a source database and place staged data into a target DB. Some access file shares and the like.

Given that setup, I like to use the SAME logging package (log4net) over and over. I keep the config in each app.config. But, I keep finding that I have "carry along" the DLL for log4net along with me.

What I mean is that when I start a new project, I have to make a reference to log4net. I have chosen not to put log4net in the GAC or install it fully to my dev machine. Instead I have the entire download package in a directory and usually do this:

I grab the DLL and create a /lib directory in my console app project and I reference that.

The upsides to this seam to be that I ALWAYS know I have the right version because I copy to local the DLL. I also check it in with the project.

But, the downside is that I end up with tons of projects each with a /lib directory, often with the same DLLs present.

What am I doing wrong? Am I just missing the entire idea behind solution/project development? I feel like my projects are all so disparate that I don't want them all to load up in one solution.

I am curious to hear how others tackle this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)? You should be able to ilmerge your log4net.dll into you executable to make it standalone.

Example usage (as a post-build step):

```
"$(SolutionDir)Lib\ilmerge" /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 /out:$(ProjectDir)bin\Merged\MyExe.exe MyExe.exe log4net.net40.dll
```

Comment: Hmm, I misread the question. We have a Solution /Lib directory. Having separate/duplicate /lib directories isn't bad. IMO, it's good. It lets you upgrade each project independently as time permits. It also sounds like you should look at NuGet for package management. Particularly package restoration: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: Yeah I think it's really the best way for our purposes. Just wanted to see if there was some neat trick out there that I was missing. I do plan to look into NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a lib folder for every single console project just to house DLLs wouldn't serve any real purpose aside from being assured it exists locally on your machine. If you're worried about organization, that probably makes things worst, because now you have multiple duplicate copies of DLLs on your development machines and app server, all of which are the same.

And what happens when log4net releases an update? You'd then have to update every single independent/physical copy and reference for log4net, rebuild, and redeploy. And if you use multiple 3rd party DLLs other than log4net, the problem only gets worst.

That being said, when you add a third party reference, the default is it will copy to local the DLL to the build folder every time you compile, and your console programs will use that local copy. You can verify this by adding one yourself, and viewing the `Copy Local` property of the reference (which should be set to true). So basically, you've been doing extra work that VS already does for you.

What I would do is house all 3rd party DLLs in a central directory on your dev machine and just simply add references to those every time you make a console application. Every time you deploy, it will carry local copies of the DLL with it. If there is a new 3rd party dll release, you'd still have to update each reference in each solution, rebuild, and re-deploy to your apps to the app servers... *however*, the difference is you're only updating one physical copy!